# MySQL INSERT VALUES значение с кавычкой

Tags: php, mysql

Есть цикл который записывает значение переменных в БД, иногда в содержании переменной встречается кавычка и естественно происходит ошибка.... Как решить эту проблемку ?
Пример :

```
$id = 1;
$person_lastname = "D'Arcy";
$result2 = "INSERT INTO shows (id,lastname) VALUES ('$id','$person_lastname')";
mysql_query($result2)or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Должно работать) но не проверял

```
$data=preg_replace('/(")||(\')/','\\'.$1,$data);
```

Ну или если правильно то

```
 $data=mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

Где дата- полученые от пользователя данные(в которых может быть кавычка)

Comment: ага, правильно про `mysql_real_escape_string($data)`!

Comment: Та ток что перечитывал свой вопрос про регулярки, и не сразу вспомнил про эскейп)

Comment: Гдето ошибка даже здесь подсвечивает )

Comment: Точно, правлю))

upd, теперь верно

зы: Советую второй вариант использовать) от кучи глюков спасет...

Answer (score 4):

[`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) - там же вы увидите сообщение о том, что этим расширением пользоваться уже не стоит.

Альтернатива [#1 Улучшенный модуль MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php), [#2 MySQL Functions (PDO_MYSQL)](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Это может оказаться полезным: [prepared statements and stored procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php).